# Rotor replacement - both rear of eagle talon 97 all wheel drive

Tags: brake-rotor, rear

Good day,

Had a quick questions, my mechanic sent me a picture of one of my rear rotors.  He said both would need to be replaced.  I do not hear any of the typical sounds that would indicate replacement, i.e. grinding, equaling or feel any jerking movement. I think the pads are still good.

I was wondering if you could take a look at the picture of the rotor and let me know what your thoughts are in regards to chaningn the rotors.  I just dont know what they are tryign to show me with this picture.

thanks so much in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The photo suggests that the brake rotor is mostly covered in rust, the dust shield is mostly gone.

The rusted rotor implies a severe brake deficit caused by an fault in the brake system. Under normal conditions the pads would have always full contact with the rotors, not allowing any rust to form. When a large portion of the rotors is rust-covered the pads had no contact with these regions on the rotors causing thereby a severe lack of braking effect.

With this photo the mechanic wants to tell you the following:

The rotors are supposed to be replaced (or resurfaced, provided he has the machinery and the rotor has sufficient thickness), including the dust shields and he has to find and solve the issue that caused the brake fault (most likely a defect in the caliper slides). The pads are always to be replaced when the rotors are replaced, especially when the pads had only partial contact with the rotors causing abnormal usage.